# Convert a condition to Option in Scala

Tags: scala

I want do something like this.

```
if (x > 0) {
  Some(123)
} else {
  None
}
```

The shorter way would be the following.

```
Try(x > 0).toOption.map(_ => 123)
```

It seems little bit unnatural for me to use `Try` (which is designed to catch exceptions) for checking a condition. Are there other ways of accomplishing this?

Edit:

`Try` doesn't work because `x > 0` doesn't throw an exception when x is negative.

Comment: Really though, there's nothing wrong with saying `val y = if(x > 0) Some(123) else None`

Comment: Your `Try` method doesn't appear to work.  I get the same result with either `Try(true)` or `Try(false)`.

Comment: @jwvh My bad. I'll update the description. Thanks.

Comment: `Try(1/math.sqrt(x))` would work :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Some(x).filter(_ > 0).map(_ => 123)
```

With `Option` you can use `filter` and `map`.

Comment: Good answer. Alternative (more generic) approach is to use `PartialFunction`:   `({case x if x > 0 => 123}: PartialFunction[Int, Int]).lift`, however, as Scala is not able to infer partial function type, it's not as convenient.

Comment: Shorter still would be `Option(123).filter(_ => x > 0)`

Comment: This is not any clearer than `if`, but for the sake of completeness: `for { o <- Some(123); if x > 0 } yield o`

Comment: This has the disadvantage of being strict in `x`.

Comment: Sheesh. Just use the `if` (#1 and #2) from here apply: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Programming_Style

Comment: @ChrisMartin how is it a "disadvantage"? And anyway, a "disadvantage", _compared to what_?

Comment: Unlike OP's original `if` expression, which is nonstrict, this expression requires evaluating the argument to `Some` regardless of whether it will just get immediately discarded by the filter. If it's expensive, this could be a performance concern.

Answer (score 23):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, `Option` is provided with the method [`when`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Option$.html#when[A](cond:Boolean)(a:=%3EA):Option[A]), which produces `Some(a)` if `a` matches the condition and `None` otherwise:

```
// val x = 45
Option.when(x > 0)(x)
// Option[Int] = Some(45)

// val x = -6
Option.when(x > 0)(x)
// Option[Int] = None

// val x = 45
Option.when(x > 0)(123)
// Option[Int] = Some(123)
```